# Get a $date between start and end dates on a continuous loop

Tags: php, loops, while-loop

Trying to figure out a way of achieving the following scenario:-

The user creates an initial time period e.g. 01/01/2013 to 01/07/2013 and a renewal period e.g. every 1 month.

I'm working on a function that will:-

1. Detect whether the date passed in a function (could be any date) falls a period matching the users requirements.

For example:-

The function may accept the following date 21/02/2019. Based on this I need to detect which renewal period the user is in.

The way I was thinking of achieving this is by:-

1. Add one day to the users initial start date to get the newest renewal date.
2. Add the renewal period (1 month) to this to get the newest end date.
3. Keep doing this until I detect which start and end dates the date falls between based on the users renewal period type e.g. 1 month.

A bit confusing but this kind of sums up what I'm after but isn't working:-

```
$tmpStartDate=$endDate;   
do{
$tmpStartDate=date("Ymd",strtotime($tmpStartDate .'+1 Day'));
$tmpEndDate=date("Ymd",strtotime($tmpStartDate .'+'.$timingUnitVal .' '.$timingUnit));
} while($date<$tmpStartDate&&$date>$tmpEndDate);
```

$endDate is the end date initially entered by the user.

Comment: this looks like PHP; if it is, you may want to tag it so.

Comment: I think the scenario as written is a bit confusing and the requirements are unclear. I think maybe if you can make the logic clearer (i.e. so that you can explain it in a single sentence or two) the solution will present itself. It sounds like the method to do this would need to use three input values, not just one, perhaps you an clarify (it sounds like you are on the right track though in terms of using strtotime() comparisons, just that the question could do with re-writing).

Answer (score 1):

From what I can gather from your question, something roughly along these lines would be more correct?

```
function findPeriod($lowerBound, $upperBound, $repeatEvery, $date)
{
  $lowerBound = strtotime($lowerBound);
  $upperBound = strtotime($upperBound);
  $repeatEvery = strtotime('+' . $repeatEvery) - time();
  $date = strtotime($date);

  while ($date >= $lowerBound) {
    if ($date <= $upperBound) {
      return array($lowerBound, $upperBound);
    } else {
      $lowerBound += $repeatEvery;
      $upperBound += $repeatEvery;
    }
  }

  return false;
}
```